# Unable login into app Firebase Auth

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication

When I try to login using any account the login page doesn't go the next activity. It doesn't even show me the next any error as I've used `getException().getMessage()` methods

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText loginEmailText;
private EditText loginPassText;
private Button loginBtn;
private Button loginRegBtn;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// private ProgressBar loginProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    loginEmailText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    loginPassText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    loginRegBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.login_reg_btn);
   // loginProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            String loginEmail = loginEmailText.getText().toString();
            String loginPass = loginPassText.getText().toString();

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(loginEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(loginPass)){
               //loginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail, loginPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            sentToMain();

                        } else {
                            String errorMessage = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"OOPs! Enter The Correct Information " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                       //loginProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser != null){
        sentToMain();
    }
}

private void sentToMain() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Did you create user first?

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: yeah i have create a new user and also its doesn't show me any errors